# How to swap memory between two void pointers in c

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to swap the memory that is pointed to by two void pointers. I get an error because I can't do a sizeof on a void, or size of an element of pa or pb (because you can't dereference a void pointer). The problem is I can't determine what data type pa and pb are going to be at runtime(this is supposed to swap any data type sent as parameters). How would I determine that so I can properly use malloc? Here is my code:

```
void SwapObjects(void *pa, void *pb, size_t size)
{
    void *pc; 
    if ((pc = (malloc(size * sizeof(pa)) == NULL))) //this is wrong         {
        printf("Cannot allocate memory");
        return;
    }
    memcpy(pc, pa, size); //runtime error here
    memcpy(pa, pb, size);
    memcpy(pb, pc, size);
}
```

Comment: You probably should use the "size" parameter instead of "size * sizeof(pa)".

Comment: What error you get, because `sizeof(void)` doesn't make any sense at all but `sizeof(pa) == sizeof(void *)` which does make sense. The code you have as is, allocates more memory than needed, but other than that it should work.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is wrong because of parentheses

```
if ((pc = (malloc(size * sizeof(pa)) == NULL)))
/* ^^     ^---------------------------------^^^ 
 * ||________________________________________|| 
 * |__________________________________________|
 */
```

and as you see you are assigning the result of `malloc(size * sizeof(pa)) == NULL` to `pc` which is a pointer and that's of course, wrong.

It should be

```
if ((pc = malloc(size)) == NULL)
```

also you are allocating more memory than needed, trying to make your code compact doesn't make it better, you could have avoided all this by just doing this

```
pc = malloc(size);
if (pc == NULL)
```

it's clearer and will not cause the error.

If your code was to remain as is, you also need to `free(pc)` because other wise you will have a memory leak every time you call `SwapObjects()`.

Since they all are just pointers, you only need to reassign the pointers instead of unnecessarily copying the data

```
void SwapObjects(void **pa, void **pb)
{
    void *pc; 

    pc  = *pa;
    *pa = *pb;
    *pb = pc;
}
```

and then

```
SwapObjects(&pa, &pb);
```

will have the same effect without the memory leak in your code.

If you really need to swap the contents fix your code as explained above.

Comment: What if I have 50 pointers pointing to the first memory block and 60 pointers pointing to the second memory block? And don't have any mechanism to enumerate these pointers. How do you suggest I should go about "reassigning the pointers"? I think if the OP says they need to physically swap memory contents, then they have a good reason to physically swap memory contents, not pointers.

Comment: @AnT Can you explain why would someone do that? is it the they don't like the location where the data is stored? is it that it matters, it could, but in exceptionally special situations. If you give a reason, please be clear.

Comment: @AnT I think you mean they access it through another pointer, I didn't think of that, from the context it seems reasonable to assume that they don't unless it's specified in the question.

Comment: To me it seems to be reasonable to assume that they *do* have other pointers, unless it is specified otherwise in the question. It is usually customary to assume the more *general* (i.e. *worse*) case. I think if the OP could just swap the pointers, they wouldn't be asking the question in the first place.

Comment: @AnT You may be right, but my answer addresses the issue, and suggests swapping the pointers, the OP might take that or not.

Answer (score 2):

You could avoid using `malloc()` altogether

```
void SwapObjects(void *pa, void *pb, size_t size) {
    unsigned char tmp;
    unsigned char *a = pa, *b = pb;
    while(size--) {
        tmp = *a;
        *a++ = *b;
        *b++ = tmp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you use `memcpy`?

Comment: @ iharob: How would you use `memcpy` in this case?

Comment: the OP's question has only the problems mentioned in my answer, as you can see, but the OP is correctly using `memcpy()` although not `malloc()`.

Comment: @iharob: Yes, but the whole point of this answer is how to do the same thing without a buffer of run-time size. I.e. how to solve the problem without `malloc`. And if there`s no `malloc` (which is the whole point), I don't see any use for `memcpy` here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure I understand your intent.

1. Do you want pointer A to reference pointer B's memory and vice versa?  (Using your function signature):

   ```
   void SwapObjects( void *pa, void *pb )
   {
     void *pTemp = pa;
     pa = pb;
     pb = pTemp;
   }
   ```
2. Do you want to copy the memory referenced by each pointer to the other's buffer?

   Note that there's no guarantee that this will work in the general case, because this function can't *know* the size of the pool referenced by each pointer--this information is not available to the programmer via any supported language construct in C.  How the compiler keeps track of the size of the pool is up to the specific compiler, typically by storing information at a negative offset from the pointer address you have been given by malloc().

   So that means you will need to ask the caller to give your function buffer sizes that you must blindly trust (== unsafe!).  You could be truncating data, or worse, reading past the end of valid data within a buffer, reading past the end of a buffer or writing past the end of a buffer.  Unless this function can guarantee these buffer sizes (ie. the function itself allocates the buffers, or you have some form of strong contract with your callers) you should consider this code to be unsafe.

   The parameters sizeA and sizeB are assumed to be in bytes, not elements.

   Final point, don't forget to free() your malloc()'s!

   ```
   /* This function is unsafe! Buffer sizes are not validated */
   void SwapOpbjects(void *pa, size_t sizeA, void *pb, size_t sizeB)
   {
     /* TODO: Ensure pa and pb are both non-NULL */
     /* TODO: Ensure sizeA and sizeB are both > 0 */

     void *pTemp = malloc( sizeA );
     if( !pTemp )
     {
       printf("malloc() failed!");
       return;
     }

     memcpy( pTemp, pa, sizeA ); /* Safe, since we allocated pTemp ourselves */
     memcpy( pa, pb, sizeB );    /* Unsafe! let's hope pa's pool is big enough to hold sizeB bytes; or you could risk truncating sizeB by only copying sizeA bytes...  Neither choice is a great one */
     memcpy( pb, pTemp, sizeA ); /* Unsafe!  As per above. */

     free( pTemp );
   }
   ```

Recommendation: stick with solution #1, or if that's not feasible, let us know use case so that the solutions can be best practices examples.

Good luck!